# Scrolling with scroll wheel doesn't render, scrolling by clicking-dragging scrollbar works fine

Tags: xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

Sometimes in my UWP app I experience a problem while scrolling with my scrollwheel. Basically the scrollbar moves when I use my scrollwheel, but the content isn't rendered properly; resulting in an empty block which gets scrolled up and down.

Yet everything works fine when I click and hold the scrollbar instead of using the scrollwheel on my mouse.

I have to restart my UWP app in order to get things back to normal.
The issue appears while scrolling a default XAML ListView, but also in a RadDataGrid (Telerik).

I have made a screen recordingo of this issue, which hopefully will illustrate what's happening more clearly. 
[Click to see video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y7b5sk3gny4fr1u/Scrolling-issue-uwp-raddatagrid.mp4?dl=0)

I haven't found exact steps to reproduce this issue, it just seems to be there at random from time to time.

Does anybody have an idea what might be going on here and how this could be fixed?

Comment: Could you try to create a minimal simple sample to help us look into this issue?

Comment: We have the same bug with UWP applications. It does not always happen, I've seen it happen even with UWP Windows applications from Microsoft.

Comment: I migrated from Template10 to the windows template studio template, and upgraded to target .NET platfrom 17134, min version 16299. I thought that fixed the issue. However I still see the bug occasionally on some computers. After restarting the UWP app it works again. Can't really reproduce this issue as it appears to occur randomly and not on all computers.

Comment: Considering the randomness I find it difficult to create a minimal sample where the issue occurs. For reference here's the Shell.xaml I'm using: https://pastebin.com/PfBbZyG2 Page content with the scrolling issues is in shellFrame

Comment: We have the same bug too, it seems to happen more often when projected to a secondary monitor.